# Changing the webdriver context to 'WEBVIEW'

Tags: selenium, webview, protractor, appium

We're using Protractor and Appium to write tests for a hybrid native application.

I'm having intermittent trouble with the 'autowebview' appium capability.  I suspect it is a race condition between a slow emulator changing contexts and protractor sending commands only supported by a webview context.

What I'd like to do is manually set the context to WEBVIEW, in Protractor's onPrepare callback, thanking that this will cut off the race condition described above.

There are code snippets out there like the following that switch the context:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var wd = require('wd'),
          wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd),
           _ = require('underscore');

    wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);

    return wdBrowser.contexts().then(function (ctxs) {
        var webCtx = _(ctxs).find(function (ctx) {
            return ctx.match(/WEBVIEW/);
        });
        return wdBrowser.context(webCtx)
    });
}
```

However, in my case 'wdBrowser.contexts' is undefined.  'wdBrowser' is a global created by wdBridge; it's defined, but that function is undefined on it, and there's no reference to 'contexts' in the wd-bridge repo.  I see that it is a [defined command in wd](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/8058f745e273693ec12a6b81f54bb501c38261a4/lib/commands.js#L313), but I can't find a reference in the WebDriverJS API docs.

Interestingly, it's clearly defined by WebdriverIO, in it's [appium section](http://webdriver.io/api/appium/contexts.html).  I'm not quite ready to give up on protractor and wd yet though.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with appium but it looks like the pattern outlined in the wd-bridge docs is to to initialize before `onPrepare` and only call `wdBridge.initFromProtractor`  in the `onPrepare` block. There [appum examples](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/node/protractor-bridge/conf.js#L22) also adds some custom capabilities for IOS, so perhaps that is needed as well.

Comment: I'll take a look, @NickTomlin, thanks.  I've seen some examples showing the wdBridge init return a promise that resolves a driver instance.  Maybe I'm trying to access the contexts properly, but before they've been initialized?